# Ways to refer to a research topic

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I look for a construction to start a sentence about previous studies on something, something like

> **In the field of reading comprehension**, some studies investigated the effect of visual structure on reading comprehension.
>
> In the topic of reading comprehension, some studies ....
>
> In reading compression studies, some studies ....
>
> In the ground of reading comprehension, some studies ...

I don't think that is a field. So what are other alternatives for  it? Also I am not certain about the proposition "in" for topic.

---

**Update**: Regarding comments, here is more context:

> There are numerous  studies on extracting the main content from web pages.  .....It also enables end users to access the web more easily ....
> ....
> Some other studies focus on the readability enhancement on the user interface level .....
> ......
> In the case of small screen devices, some attention has been given to using dynamically altered presentation of text.
> ............
> Some studies investigated the effect of text signals and visual structure on reading comprehension

Comment: Why front the field? You're mentioning it again at the end of the sentence, so readers will understand what the field is. Just start "Some studies have investigated &c"

Comment: @StoneyB in reviewing previous works, I jump from topic A, to topic B, then I thought to signal user and make emphasis that I am going to review the next topic, I'd better start the sentence by mentioning the field.

Comment: Then just fold it into the subject: "Reading comprehension studies have investigated the effect of visual structure; ... " There's no need to distinguish the field from studies *in* the field ... practically, the studies **are** the field!

Comment: If you are trying to differentiate between a previous different topic and the quote in your question, could you add such a previous topic to the text in your example? Then it might be clearer why you are asking about this.

Comment: @user3169 I did, I liked something similar to the previous paragraph *in the case of small screen devices...*, regardless of these, suppose one want to introduce a sentence like that, what are options?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I sort of agree "field" doesn't sound very right here. There are many options, and they can vary based on whether the phrase/word suits it. In your case, I might recommend:

> In the **area** of reading comprehension, some studies investigated the effect of visual structure on reading comprehension.

Another word can be:

> **scope**